# Classpath unsets after restarting

Tags: java

I have followed the steps illustrated in this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_packages.htm but after I restart my system(Ubuntu 12.10) the classpath unsets itself. How can I make it more permanent?

Comment: question belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to export the path variable for every start again. This could be done in the file **.bashrc** or **.profile** in the home folder.

By the way: this is not the right site for asking such questions, do it here: http://unix.stackexchange.com

Have a look:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14594/how-to-make-exported-shell-variables-permanent
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/
- http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Environment_Variables.html

Comment: thanks :) it worked but used nano instead of vi. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your home directory's .bash_profile file and set the classpath there like:

```
export CLASSPATH=...
```

Comment: will not help when rebooting for that yiou have to make the export in the .bash-rc

Comment: Sure it will. Of course it will affect only that particular user, but in most cases it would be enough.

Comment: how can I export it to .bash-rc? I didn't find any file like that when I checked home

Comment: @Kayaman: No it will not. The command export makes the variable only available for child processes. After a reboot of the system those variables are lost and have to get reinitialized.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-shell-export-command/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328223/unix-export-command http://www.unix.com/unix-advanced-expert-users/45430-export-command.html