# permanant way of antlr4 set to working

Tags: 14.04

i am using ubuntu 14.04 and i have to follow a list of 3-4 steps to use antlr4 for parsing (everytime).In windows there is a temporary as well as a permanent way .but in ubuntu every time terminal opens then i have to follow these steps given on the official website.

```
http://www.antlr.org/
```

4 steps are:

```
$cd /usr/local/lib
$ sudo curl -O http://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.4-complete.jar
$ export CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.4-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH"
$ alias antlr4='java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.4-complete.jar'
$ alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig'
```

curl is for downloading once into usr\local\lib

is there any permanent way of getting anlr4 work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These 2 lines are needed one time only:

```
$ cd /usr/local/lib
$ sudo curl -O http://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.4-complete.jar
```

It is for download the antlr jar file so this is only needed once.

These lines need to be edited into a start up file for your session (or any user on your system that needs to use this).

```
$ export CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.4-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH"
$ alias antlr4='java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.4-complete.jar'
$ alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig'
```

I would suggest .bashrc in /home/$USER/

- Regarding classpath: [Classpath unsets after restarting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316122/classpath-unsets-after-restarting)
- Regarding aliases: [How do I create a permanent Bash alias?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias)

Comment: can you pass me a link about .bashrc as i rarely use ubuntu, and i don't know even basic things about that.

Comment: Is this sufficient:http://askubuntu.com/questions/540683/what-is-a-bashrc-file-and-what-does-it-do ?